# Public IEnumerator not being ran even when called?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

please excuse the messy code, all of this was written very hastily because I'm on a time crunch

```
    public class EnemyShoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform player;
    public float speed = 100f;
    public float angle;
    public Quaternion rotation;
    bool allowforfire;
    [SerializeField] float bulletSpeed, firerate;
    private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 direction = player.position - transform.position;
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(player.position.x < transform.parent.position.x)
        {
             transform.localPosition = new Vector2(-0.155f, 0f);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.localPosition = new Vector2(0.155f, 0f);
        }

        
    }
    public IEnumerator Shoot(GameObject bullet)
    {
        Debug.Log("reached shoot");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(firerate);
        var clone = Instantiate(bullet, transform);
        var bulletRb = clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        bulletRb.velocity = transform.right * bulletSpeed;
        Debug.Log("reached fire");
        clone.transform.position = new Vector3(clone.transform.position.x, clone.transform.position.y, -1f);
    }
}
```

so I have this IEnumerator that I need to be called in another script so I included everything from the script its from. the problem is that even though I am getting zero errors in both unity and vs its not even being run when called since no matter where in the method I put the debug.log it never gets to unity's console (yes, its in debugging mode)

this is the important part of the script its called in:

```
 public int robohealth = 4;
    public float speed = 0.2f;
    public float minMoveDist = 3f;
    public SpriteRenderer roboSprite;
    Vector3 oldPos;
    public Animator roboAnim;
    [SerializeField] Transform target;
    public GameObject roboBullet;
    public EnemyShoot shootScript;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (target != null)
        {
            float trueSpeed;
            float PositionDelta = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.position);
            if(PositionDelta < minMoveDist)
            {
                trueSpeed = 0f;
                
            }
            else
            {
                trueSpeed = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, trueSpeed);

            if (oldPos != transform.position)
            {
                roboAnim.SetBool("ShouldWalk", true);
            }
            else 
            { 
                roboAnim.SetBool("ShouldWalk", false);
                //not working ):
                shootScript.Shoot(roboBullet);
            }
            

            oldPos = transform.position;
        }
        
        roboSprite.flipX = transform.position.x > target.position.x;
    }
```

anyone got any clue as to where I went wrong?

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace please?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your method `Shoot`  does not really return a **collection**, but an **iterator** on a collection. That's what we call [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-lazy-evaluation). So the code is only executed, when you're calling `Next` on that iterator, which is typically achieved by using some `foreach`-loop. Imagine the following code:

```
IEnumerable<int> MyMethod() 
{
    yield return 3;
    yield return 5;
    yield return 7;
}
```

Now you're trying to call that method:

```
var result = MyMethod();
```

As the method is **deferredely executed** (that's what the [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)-keyword is for), that above assignment won't return all the three numbers, but just an iterator to them. You can't do much with it, unless you *execute* the iterator like this:

```
foreach(var number in result)
    Console.WriteLine(number);
```

In your case I can't see why your method should even return *anything*, as you're not using the iterator in any way. So I'd suggest to make your method a `void` and change this line

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(firerate);
```

to

```
WaitForSeconds(firerate);
```

Comment: could you translate that into normal-people speak? I don't understand what that means

Comment: @OliverSalesJäderberg I'm not sure what you mean by "normal-people speak", but the linq anove should give you a deeper understanding how deferred execution works. Basically the `yield`-keywords indicates that your method *is* executed deferredly. What that means is written in the link.

Comment: I'm just extremely bad with any actual concepts and terminology in programming, I basically know syntax. so stuff happens when I type but as to what Im doing is called Im clueless. for example I have zero idea what an IEnumerator is its just something I found someone using on google for basically the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

To call a `public IEnumerator`, you can't just call it as a method, you have to start the coroutine

```
StartCoroutine(Shoot(roboBullet));
```

For more info on Coroutines, refer to [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)